# Underlined text field in a fillable form

Tags: text-decorations, forms

Is there a way to make an underlined text field in a fillable form?

I am using the `hyperref` package to make a fillable form but I would also like to give the option of printing out the form and filling it by hand. For the later, a line is helpful to serve as guide for the pen.

This

```
\TextField[name=firstname,width=5cm,charsize=11pt]{First Name}
```

gives an empty box and I cannot find an easy way to underline this box.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Answer (score 13):

The printing of the field is controlled by `\MakeTextField` whose default definition is equivalent to

```
\newcommand{MakeTextField}[2]{\vbox to #2{\hbox to #1{\hfill}\vfill}}
```

Replacing the inside `\hfill` with an `\hrulefill` produces a horizontal line, but because of the placing of the `\vfill` these will be at the top of the box.  Moving the placement of `\vfill` gives a line at the bottom via

```
\renewcommand{\MakeTextField}[2]{{\vbox to #2{\vfill\hbox to #1{\hrulefill}}}}
```

You will probably want to adjust the colour to black (rather than the gray I get as default):

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref,xcolor}

\renewcommand{\MakeTextField}[2]{{\vbox to #2{\vfill\hbox to #1{\hrulefill}}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
  \TextField[name=firstname,width=5cm,charsize=11pt,color=black]{First Name}
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Strangely, this doesn't seem to do anything in `pdflatex`, though it does give lines in `xelatex`. You wouldn't know why that is, would you?

Comment: The above sample is `pdflatex`, so I guess it is an April fool.

Comment: This also does not work for me on a recent version of pdflatex (but works fine with xelatex). It results in an overfull vbox as well.

Comment: @SamWhited Still working fine for me (`pdflatex` an a mac, texlive 2018).  Perhaps you should make a new post with your set-up details.

Comment: I had to set the `backgroundcolor={}` so I could see the line.