# Latex forms, MakeTextField, LayoutTextField and javascript questions

Tags: hyperref, text-decorations, forms, javascript

I trying to do underlined `TextField` with label under the field (`hyperref` package).

using [Underlined text field in a fillable form](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101628/underlined-text-field-in-a-fillable-form/101646)

i tried to renew MakeTextField:

```
\renewcommand{\MakeTextField}[2]{{\vbox to #2{\vfill\hbox to #1{\hrulefill}}}}
```

But before i can see it like underline, i had to insert this code:

```
\begin{insDLJS}{mydljs}{ }
    this.getField('name').fillColor=color.transparent;
    this.getField('name').borderColor=color.transparent;
\end{insDLJS}
```

So first questions are:

1. why i see it like boxes, without javascript code?
2. i have to insert
       it's for all fields? Maybe you know have to do it easler?

Then i tried to renew LayoutTextField, best try:

```
\renewcommand{\LayoutTextField}[2]{%
\vbox to \baselineskip{%
 \hbox to \DefaultWidthofText{\makebox[\width]{#2}}%
 \hbox to \DefaultWidthofText{\hfill\makebox[\width]{#1} \hfill}%
}}
```

result:

[image: result]

And i can't centering it, i can't get width of field and use it when i placing label.
questions:

1. How can i get size of Textfield in `LayoutTextField`?
2. How centering label?

i can center it only using ugly

```
\renewcommand{\LayoutTextField}[2]{%
\begin{tabular}{c}%
\\%
#2  \\%
\hline%
\small{#1}%
\end{tabular}%
}
```

without `\renewcommand{\MakeTextField}` , but it's disgusting, and create vertical spaces :(

Then i create textfield to enter date and found 2 problems:

1. I can't insert russian text using javascript.
2. I can't to use percent symbol (%)  in javascript code in `keystroke` inside `TextField`)

First problem i solve using unicode. I wrote small python script to convert text from cp-1251 to unicode, example:

```
>>> unicode("Январь","cp1251")
u'\u042f\u043d\u0432\u0430\u0440\u044c'
```

and then insert it into javascript, and it's works :) but it's hard to read and edit this, mb smb known another way?

Second problem i solve using `insDLJS` (\%) without it problem with backslash (\) and (%). I'm very lazy, and maybe smb know, how i can use it inside `keystroke`,`format`,`calculate`, etc.?