# TextField underlined

Tags: hyperref, pdf, baseline

Can someone show me the necessary code to get an underlined textfield in latex? I want the solution to be as simple as possible so that I can customize it as needed.

Ideally, I would prefer something like,

```
\TextField[name=box1,baseline=true]{text (not underlined)}
```

I have tried the solution here (which does not work):
[underlined text field in a fillable form](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101628/underlined-text-field-in-a-fillable-form)

as well as this solution (which I cannot figure out how to change simply):
[creating fillable PDFs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14842/creating-fillable-pdfs?rq=1)

If someone could provide a simple method for underlining the fillable area, or can explain how to make the first solution work for pdflatex, it would help me a lot.

Comment: Do you want the text inside the `\TextField` to be underlined, or the `\TextField` itself to be underlined? I'm assuming the former...

Comment: Welcome! Please provide a compilable minimal example rather than a code fragment as it will be much easier to help and much more likely you'll get a solution you consider simple which is, frankly, a relative term.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
\let\oldTextField\TextField
\renewcommand{\TextField}[2][] {
        \vbox{\hbox{\oldTextField[#1]{#2}}\kern2pt\hrule}
}
```

If you DON'T want a box, try adding `borderwidth=0` after `#1`.
Don't forget the `,`.

This does not work well with multiline textfields.
I did put this answer together from the links you provided (I had issues with the solutions as well).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is to use the `borderstyle=U` option.

```
\TextField[name=box1,borderstyle=U]{text (not underlined)}
```

But, it should better align if you write:

```
\mbox{text (not underlined)~\TextField[name=box1,borderstyle=U]{}}
```